# How to check if the data was written to firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using this code after submit is pressed to add data to my firebase database.

I want to redirect it to a new page after the data has been written, but I cannot figure out a way to check if data is written in database.

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
var details = document.getElementById("details");

function submit() {
    if(!(email.value == null)) {
        var storage = firebase.storage();
        var ref = storage.ref();
        var letters = ref.child('letters');
        var userref = letters.child(email.value+".txt");
        var data = details.value;
        userref.putString(data);
        var database = firebase.database();
        var databaseref = database.ref().child("users");
        databaseref.child(email.value).set({email: email.value,phone:phone.value},);
        // tried this window.alert("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is example is from the firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set):

```
adaNameRef.set({ first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace' })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Synchronization failed');
  });
```

You can see that the `.set` method returns a firebase promise which will resolve if the data updated successfully and reject if it doesn't.

You should redirect in the same place that `console.log('Synchronization succeeded');` is running in the example.